# Can't get info on os.path attribute in python

Tags: python, function, object, attr

I'm trying to understand the expression structure of `os.path.isdir`

If type:

```
help(os)
```

I am provided with a list of 'things' python can use from `os`

I can't find an entry there called `path` rather `pathconf(...)`

However, when I type:

```
help(os.path)
```

The options I am provided include `isdir(s)`

Why am I not seeing information about `path`?

Answer (score 4):

That's because the name `path` is not defined directly in the module `os.py`.  Instead, it's imported from elsewhere and aliased.  The implementation is platform-dependent.

On [Windows systems](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4b93554253f461ecf0f384a2bdff83f1fe08722a/Lib/os.py#L77) you will have:

```
import ntpath as path
```

On [Linux / macOS](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4b93554253f461ecf0f384a2bdff83f1fe08722a/Lib/os.py#L57) you will have:

```
import posixpath as path
```

Since `os.path` is just a reference to another module such as `posixpath`, or `ntpath`, you can always look at `help(os.path)`.

Answer (score 1):

`os.path` is a module. Therefore it does not appear in the help for `os`. Rather it has its own help. `os.path.__file__` will show you the actual path of this module. From the docs of `os`:

> - os.path is either posixpath or ntpath

Relevant part of the source of `os`:

```
if 'posix' in _names:
    # ...
    import posixpath as path
elif 'nt' in _names:
    # ...
    import ntpath as path
```

Comment: I find that rather confusing since up until now I understood that the dotting convention was used to indicate a structure change between say `module.class.function` - I would have thought that a module made up of two words would follow python convention and separate like `osPath` or `os_path` rather than using a `.` Unless I just totally misunderstood the usage of `.`

Comment: Yeah, you misunderstood the usage.  `x.y` just means lookup attribute `y` on object `x`, the hierarchy of objects here does not specifically have to be `module` -> `class` -> `function` (although that is a common pattern).  In the case of `os.path.isdir` it's `module` -> `module` -> `function`.

Comment: The dot gives you access to an attribute. In this case the module `os` imports `path`. Therefore, you can reach it via `module.attribute`, i.e. `os.path`. Or, `path` is just a global name in `os`.

Answer (score 0):

`os` is `/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py` and `os.path` is `/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py` (or `ntpath.py` on Windows). The `help` function simply reads the docstrings from those two files.